# La expresión regular siempre retorna false

Tags: c#, mvc, regex

Estoy haciendo la verificación de un correo como entrenamiento y estoy trabajando con expresiones regulares para hacer las validaciones con c#. Ya intente varias cosas pero por algún motivo siempre me marca que *el correo no es valido*, pero no encuentro errores; el condicional y la expresión regular están bien (me encargue de probarla antes en una pagina web y luego en el buscador incorporado de c# y con las dos encuentra los correos electrónicos).

Agradecería que alguien que pueda tener idea del error que estoy cometiendo me lo hiciera saber.

Código de la vista:

```
private void btnAgregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string correo = txtCorreo.Text;
    string rol = cbxRol.Text;

    Controlador.Controlador controlador = new Controlador.Controlador();

    string respuesta = controlador.ctrlAgregar(correo, rol);

    if(respuesta.Length > 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(respuesta);
    }
            
}
```

Código del controlador:

```
public string ctrlAgregar(string usuario, string rol)
{
    string respuesta = "";

    if (Regex.IsMatch(usuario, @"/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}$)?/g"))
    {
        return respuesta;
    }
    else
    {
        respuesta = "Ese correo no es valido";
    }           
    return respuesta;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Digamos que usaste https://regexr.com/ para verificar tu expresión regular. Esa web está pensada para probar expresiones regulares en JavaScript. En él, necesita las partes que se encuentran en gris.

[image: Ejemplo]

En C#, no son necesarias. Entonces con quitárselas, tu expresión debería funcionar. Quedaría algo así:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}$)?
```

La forma de pasárselo es agregando comillas al inicio y al final, como un String, y añadiéndole un @ antes de la primera comilla, para evitar que las barras invertidas se consideren caracteres de escape.

Teniendo en cuenta que podrías usar frecuentemente esa expresión regular, puedes guardarla en una variable fuera de la función, así:

```
Regex rgxCorreo = new Regex(@"[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}$)?");
```

Y cuando lo quieras usar, solo le pasas el String a comprobar.

```
rgxCorreo.IsMatch(usuario);
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es la REGEX, es incorrecta, para validar un email puedes usar:

```
\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)\Z
```

este sería el código:

```
public string ctrlAgregar(string usuario, string rol)
    {
        string respuesta = "";

       if (Regex.IsMatch(usuario, @"\A(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)\Z", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            return respuesta;
        }
        else
        {
            respuesta = "Ese correo no es valido";
        }           

        return respuesta;
    }
```